# How to install html-to-markdown without composer

Tags: php

I want to install html-to-markdown without composer but I can't figure it out, with other libraries like Parsedown it worked just by using file location, but with html-to-markdown I don't know what I should use
This is the [link](https://github.com/thephpleague/html-to-markdown#html-to-markdown-for-php) for html-to-markdown

Comment: With experience it's a better idea to use composer to install this kind of library

Comment: Ok so how can I include it in my project cause on other libs I use `include_once(PATH."lib/Parsedown.php");`   
For this what file name I should use cause I can't figure it out

Comment: As per its [composer settings](https://github.com/thephpleague/html-to-markdown/blob/master/composer.json#L32), this library is standalone (it doesn't depend on other packages) but it's using Composer autoloader. You need to provide your own PSR-4 compliant autoloader, or load manually every single class. What exact problem are you trying to solve with manual installation?

Answer (score 0):

In your link there is a chapter [How to use it](https://github.com/thephpleague/html-to-markdown#how-to-use-it) with step by step instructions for installation.

Make sure to add `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` to the top of your script, where you want to use the package.

Comment: `vendor/autoload.php` is a file supplied by Composer.

Answer (score 0):

First, use GitHub's "Code/ Download ZIP" option to get the code:

[image: Code/ Download ZIP]

To figure out the requirements of an application meant to be installed with Composer, you need to inspect the [`composer.json` file](https://github.com/thephpleague/html-to-markdown/blob/master/composer.json) in the root directory:

- The `require` key tells us the PHP extensions and third-party libraries needed:

  ```
  "require": {
      "php": "^7.2.5 || ^8.0",
      "ext-dom": "*",
      "ext-xml": "*"
  },
  ```

  In this case, the library is standalone, so you just need to verify your PHP installation meets the requirements. If it happened to need other packages, you'd have to repeat this for every package involved.
- The `autoload` key tells us how the library locates and opens the files with class definitions:

  ```
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "League\\HTMLToMarkdown\\": "src/"
      }
  },
  ```

  This library depends on Composer's [PSR-4 autoloader](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) implementation. We'll get back to this.

There may be other important information in the file, but in this particular case this is pretty much everything.

Regarding the autoloader... If your codebase already implements PSR-4, you just need to configure a new `League\HTMLToMarkdown` namespace and download the source code in the location expected by your autoloader, keeping the folder structure intact. Otherwise, I can think of a number of options, none of them particularly attractive:

- Write [your own autoloader](https://www.php.net/spl_autoload).
- Find a third-party PSR-4 autoloader.
- Get a list of all relevant source PHP files and load them all manually:

  ```bash
  $ find . -name '*.php'
  ./src/Environment.php
  ./src/Configuration.php
  ./src/Element.php
  ./src/ElementInterface.php
  ./src/PreConverterInterface.php
  ./src/HtmlConverterInterface.php
  ./src/ConfigurationAwareInterface.php
  ./src/Converter/TextConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/TableConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/ListItemConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/ListBlockConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/PreformattedConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/ConverterInterface.php
  ./src/Converter/DivConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/BlockquoteConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/HorizontalRuleConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/DefaultConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/CodeConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/ImageConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/HardBreakConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/ParagraphConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/EmphasisConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/CommentConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/HeaderConverter.php
  ./src/Converter/LinkConverter.php
  ./src/HtmlConverter.php
  ```

  Make this into a list of `require '...';` commands and play around with file order until you don't get errors.